# Can I use SQLite to model arbitrary graphs (i.e. a logical map with cycles)?

Tags: sqlite, database-design, data-modeling

I'm new to SQL and learning about Adjacency Lists, Nested Sets, Closure Tables, but from what I understood, these solutions usually apply to acyclic data.

I'm aware that this sort of problem may be better suited to a graphical database engine such as Neo4j, and I am exploring that also.  But for this question, I specifically want to know if I can achieve this goal in SQLite.

Before running off with a possible answer for this, please help me understand how to better define or illustrate the problem.  Once the problem definition is refined, then point me in the right direction (technique, reference material) and let me try to figure it out.

**Objectives:**

1. Maintain a list of areas and how they are connected.
2. Areas can have different types: Country, Highway, State, City, Neighborhood.
3. Areas can be connected in cycles (undirected).
4. Areas can have multiple exits.
5. Maintain a weighted list from one exit to another, within the area.
6. Extract optimal path from one area to another (from this neighborhood to nearest highway).

**Assumptions:**

1. Will use SQLite 3 (newest version).
2. Small data set ( < 1,000 areas and connections, < 5s DB creation).
3. Relatively static ( < 5 inserts or updates/year ).
4. May be simpler to recreate database from scratch than update?
5. Highways are areas, not connectors.
6. Streets are logical connectors, no length, no weight.

Areas and connections are like a house with many rooms with multiple doors.  The doors connect the rooms.  There is no traversal weight going through a door.  The weight in selecting a door comes from the distance between the doors.  A hallway is like an extended door, so it has a weight and is considered a type room.  A room may have a large size, but if the only two doors are near each other, it may have a small weight.  it's not the size of the room that counts for my purposes, but the distance between the doors.

As always, thank you for taking the time to read, and for constructive comments.

Comment: There are multiple ways to model this kind of graph. Please show the data structures you would use in some programming language.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use SQLite to store this kind of data.
It is not practical, and you may have performance issues. If you plan to store huge amount of such data and want a well scalable solution, you should go for some graph DB.

If you are gong to store ~1000 nodes, that can work with simple realtions in SQLite.

Especially since you are going to have very little number of updates, you could pre-calculate the distances. So you don't have to actually recalculate it each time, but just load from the DB.

I think you should represent your problem as a graph.

[image: Graph representation]

Nodes could be the "doors" and edges the distances between them.
You could store this easily in relational database. (Areas(Id,Name), Doors(Id,Area1,Area2) DoorDoorDistance(Door1, Door2, Distance))

If you have stored these data, you can calculate shortest path from every door to every other. You could store this in a new table. (Distances(Door1,Door2,Path, Distance))

To calculate shortest path you can find different algorithms:
[Shortest path algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem#Algorithms)

After this you have the shortest path between each pair of doors.

The only question from now is witch door to take from your starting area to which door in your destination area.

If you don't want to be this precise you just take the one with the shortest path. Otherwise you have to maintain door distances from area starting points. 
A; You can can assume that you start from the center of the area, so you can store door distances from the center
B; You can be more precise, by storing exact door locations and calculating door distances from an exact starting point.

In both cases you should select door with the lowest cost, both in the starting area and the destination area:

Total cost: (Walk to door distance) + (starting Door to destination Door Path) + (Walk to destination in the destination area)

I would do this like this. I hope I helped, have fun!